# Access current domain name on Application_Start

Tags: c#, .net, global-asax

Normally to access the current domain name e.g where the site is hosted I do something like

```
string rURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
```

But `HttpContext` is not avaible on `Application_Start` only from `Application_BeginRequest`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sort of related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180905/how-do-i-get-the-host-domain-name-in-asp-net-without-using-httpcontext-current-r

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full host name + port number in Application_Start of Global.aspx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243270/how-to-get-full-host-name-port-number-in-application-start-of-global-aspx)

Comment: Yep didn't see that when looking and it wasn't flagged when I typed the question. flagged for deletion.

Comment: You could also try [`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.sitename(v=vs.110).aspx). It's not strictly the domain name, but is the IIS site name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`Dns.GetHostName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use this in Gloabl.asax.cs, no matter within Application_Start() or not.

```
var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
```

tested in Asp.net 4.5 MVC.

Comment: Note that this may not always work as expected. For example, on my local computer I have a hosts entry for a domain (e.g. example.com), and also have bindings configured in IIS. When using this method, however, I get the computer name and not the domain name. In this scenario I get something like "vm-dev1".

Answer (score 8):

A single IIS application can be bound to many different URLs. `Application_Start` fires before any request has been received, so the only way to find the domain name to which the site is bound is to query IIS.

Even then you may not be able to get an answer - consider the situation where an application is bound to a wildcard / default hostname.

A better approach may be to look at `Application_AuthenticateRequest`. This fires before `Application_BeginRequest` and does give you a full `HttpContext.Current.Request` object.

Comment: Thought it might be something like this, putting the URL to access in the web.config I think is the best way forward.

Comment: `Application_Start` only fires when the application - eh - starts. :) Whereas `Application_AuthenticateRequest` fires on every request. This doesn't answer the question accurately.

Answer (score 3):

The IIS application does not know what domain its accessed from (see bindings) at application start.

Answer (score 3):

One way of achieving this is a little bit of a cheat and comes with caveats, and that's to use [`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.sitename(v=vs.110).aspx).

So this would look like:

```
string rURL = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
```

And now for those caveats:

- This is the name of the site in IIS.
- That means your site name can be a non-URI (eg My Awesome Site).
- If you have multiple domains sharing the same site, it'll be the same for each one.

For my purposes - setting up logging on servers where I had multiple sites in IIS pointing to the same physical folder - the above solution was probably the simplest and easiest. I'm not saying it's necessarily the 'right' answer, but it should be considered as an alternative.