# WCF REST Service Template 40(CS) Cross domain error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, wcf-rest

Hi I have a WCF Rest service using ( WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)). I have managed to get it to return Json response. It is working fine when the project is run. But when I try to make a Ajaxcall to the service  from the browser, I am getting Error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at `http://192.168.0.70:8001/Service/test`.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

And The Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.70:8001/Service/test",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
        var Tabels = msg.d;
        alert('success');
        }
    });
```

Here is the web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>

        <add name="ConString" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=fabapp;UID=root;PASSWORD=;"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <!-- 
                Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
                via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
            -->
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
      </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

I tried adding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" but when I do that the service does not work on the localhost also. I get this:

> Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated
>   services.

Anything I need to change in web.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically speaking , i had faced this issue, i have gone one step further to check WebAPI, and same effort was required, when i analysed. So i had to fix this `CORS with WCF`. I will try to explain in short. Here we go. When you access WCF request with CrossOrigin, like from JS code existing in different domain, and from JS , you try to do `PUT` or `POST` request, 1st browser sends an `OPTION` request `405 HTTP Status`, to see if this domain is in allowed list, then if your `WCF` respond to `OPTIONS` request, sends required response with header value, then browser will again do a `POST` or `PUT` request ( which ever browser issued earlier), and it will work as expected.

NOTE: you can not send `("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`, because, there is a security feature , that mandates required domain name to be listed in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` instead of `*`.

For more info -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ro-RO/5613de55-2573-49ca-a389-abacb39e4f8c/wcf-rest-service-post-cross-domain-not-working?forum=wcf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163802/wcf-cors-request-from-jquery-not-working

From practical experience, i have tried `*` in that header, it was not working. If you don't believe me, go ahead and try .

Finally the code is following. You need to put this in `Global.asax`.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String domainname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"].ToString();
    if (IsAllowedDomain(domainname))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", domainname);
    String allowedmethods =  "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET";
    String headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"].ToString();
    String accesscontrolmaxage =  "1728000";
    String contenttypeforoptionsrequest = "application/json";


    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", allowedmethods);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", accesscontrolmaxage);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentType", contenttypeforoptionsrequest);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
private bool IsAllowedDomain(String Domain)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain)) return false;
    string[] alloweddomains = "http://192.168.0.70:8001"; // you can place comma separated domains here.
    foreach (string alloweddomain in alloweddomains)
    {
        if (Domain.ToLower() == alloweddomain.ToLower())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: * is working, for some reason you just had some issues with it (possibly because of the `localhost` domain). Is this answer yours or you cited the other answer by @Samir? His answer is 2 hours earlier and yours seems like a copy-paste of his plus some comments.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes my solution is working, i mean i had used this 6 months back , and point was `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` was not working for mine, so i gone ahead to fix that, and that will send header with required domains, instead of `*`.

Comment: @ArindamNayak Ur solution isn't working. I am getting error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at this line: `String domainname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"].ToString();`

Comment: I see, you should not get error, to just give a try use `domainname` = `"http://192.168.0.70:8001/"`, see if that helps

Comment: Now I am getting same error at `String headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"].ToString();`

Comment: just use  `"Content-Type, Accept" `there, not sure why you are getting `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers` as null! or just look up in browser network console , see value for `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and use that value here!

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is working. I will test it more and let you know

Comment: How do I get current domain name instead of just hardcoding `"http://192.168.0.70:8001/"`

Comment: There are many ways, i have used above( which didn't work for you), one more way - `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] ` , more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180905/how-do-i-get-the-host-domain-name-in-asp-net-without-using-httpcontext-current

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63074/discussion-between-user1650891-and-arindam-nayak).

Comment: Now i got it, can you tell me from which domain you are executing JS, if you have used JS in "http://www.example.com" , then use following HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why is "GET" not defined in the `allowedmethods`? I get the `Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services` error when using JSON GET requests via AJAX. And even when I add `GET` to that list I still get the same error (also when trying to access the service directly via the browser address bar).

Comment: @Flo, I have updated answer to include `GET` it is working fine, i havn't added that to not to confuse OP. You need to check `alloweddomains`, it should be equal to domain, where JS call happens, say you have hosted in http://www.example1.com and make call to example2.com, then `alloweddomains` should have `http://www.example1.com`.

Comment: @ArindamNayak I tried your exact code, but still I get the same error. My services work over http, over https and when I'm not logged in, but the moment I am, the error occurs. Do I also need to alter my web services perhaps?

Comment: @Flo, if you have enabled `trace` and post those in a separate question, then i can certainly help you out.

Comment: @ArindamNayak, thanks! I've put the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824265/cross-domain-javascript-callback-is-not-supported-in-authenticated-services

Answer (score 2):

put following in global.asax file of your wcf application

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried with the solution you provide, it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the post in this link:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java
>
> Ajax allows to get data in the background without interfering with the
>   display. Ajax call done by using XMLHttpRequest object allows the
>   client side JavaScript code to make HTTP connections.  But Ajax call
>   does not allow to get data from cross-domain because of restrictions
>   imposed by the browser. Security error gets issued when requesting
>   data from another domain. One way to avoid security errors is to
>   control remote server where data resides and every request goes to the
>   same domain. That gives rise to the question, what's the fun if data
>   comes from own server only? What to do if data is required to get from
>   the other server?
>
> There is one way to come out from this limitation - to insert a
>   dynamic script element in the Web page, one whose source is pointing
>   to the service URL in the other domain and gets the data in the script
>   itself. When the script loads, it executes. It works because the
>   same-origin policy doesn't prevent dynamic script insertions and
>   treats the scripts as if they were loaded from the domain that
>   provided the Web page. But if this script tries to load a document
>   from yet another domain, it will fail. Fortunately, you can improve
>   this technique by adding JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) to the mix.
>
> JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a complement to the base JSON data
>   format, a pattern of usage that allows a page to request data from a
>   server in a different domain. As a solution to this problem, JSONP is
>   an alternative to a more recent method called Cross-Origin Resource
>   Sharing.
>
> Under the same origin policy, a web page served from
>   server1.example.com cannot normally connect to or communicate with a
>   server other than server1.example.com. An exception is the HTML
>    element. Taking advantage of the open policy for 
>   elements, some pages use them to retrieve JavaScript code that
>   operates on dynamically-generated JSON-formatted data from other
>   origins. This usage pattern is known as JSONP. Requests for JSONP
>   retrieve not JSON, but arbitrary JavaScript code. They are evaluated
>   by the JavaScript interpreter, not parsed by a JSON parser.

Personally, I have encountered this problem before, but then what I did is I changed the architecture. I usually would just call the WCF from my web server. So

> AJAX Request from Browser -> Web Server -> WCF Service

I think for security purposes, this restriction is built to prevent many security vulnerabilities. However, if you really want to achieve what you want and the previous answers don't meet your requirement, you might want to take a look at this post as alternative. It seems promising. Please keep me updated.

Hope it helps. Thanks.